# Trigger Power Automate from One Team Site to Another Team Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have 2 Team Sites, is it possible to trigger Site B Power Automate based on Site A Power Automate directly?

I am not looking moving/copying files from Site A to Site B, is more of direct workflow trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You could design these two flows as parent/child flows，for more information, please refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2019wave2/power-automate/call-child-flows

Similar issue:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Triggering-One-Flow-from-Another-Flow/td-p/611453

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Trigger-a-flow-from-within-another-flow/td-p/567303

Comment: Is the parent and child flow to be resided in same Team Site? Or, they are in its own Team Site?